# How the firewall is allowing Facebook requests to bypass itself?

Tags: networking, nat

I've a McAfee Firewall configured at my workplace. It actively blocks all the requests for websites like

```
 https://www.Flipkart.com
 https://www.Amazon.com
 https://www.Facebook.com
```

I's playing around with requests and discovered that McAfee doesn't blocks Facebook on trying

```
  https://www.facebook.com/pages
```

And I can peacefully sign into my FB account using the login page coming up from the above request. Then I tried same with Flipkart and Amazon but couldn't succeed. I wish to know how the filtering rules get violated for Facebook while they are still blocking
other websites like Amazon and Flipkart. I can easily make out that the IT team must have missed something
with the filtering rules (FB site)? Any details on this query will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a specific McAfee configuration question. Perhaps McAfee support could help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though they have just blacklisted the base URL; www.facebook.com, not the entire domain. This has probably been bolted on as a new rule in your firewall, and misconfigured.

If you were to try some other IPs for Amazon, or other Amazon domains, you might get lucky, otherwise it may have been configured correctly for the other two.

Ofcourse, it's completely up to you if you spend more time on trying to evade these rules at work or not.